# Weight only the negative or the positive samples in the class

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision

Algorithm i am trying to implement deals with class imbalances in the dataset. I have 40 classes of CelebA dataset which is a multi label dataset and wants to balance the dataset dynamically. I am using keras but having trouble coming up with the right logic to solve the problem.

**Algorithm**

- Positive and Negative samples in the class should be equal
- If positive sample instance are greater in a class then simply select the targeted amount of samples from them and weight the negative instances i.e if batch size is 100 and there are 70 positive instances and 30 negative instances in a class then randomly choose 50 from the positive instances and assign weight 50/30=5/3 to negative samples and vice versa in case of negative over represented instances

**Problem**

- I am using Keras to implement a deep learning problem with the mentioned algorithm. How can i assign only negative or positive instances a weight instead of all the instances like it does when you use ***sample_weights***.
- If i try to balance the samples by simply duplicating then i run into some sort of circular paradox i.e if i balance one class of over represented instances by removing samples then another class may get under represented and when i duplicate this new under represented class, the previous class may get over represented.

Kindly let me know what is the most efficient way to solve the mentioned algorithm in Keras. For further help you can check out the research paper here: https://www.cs.umd.edu/~emhand/Papers/AAAI2018_SelectiveLearning.pdf?fbclid=IwAR13MMtV4TpVSerMZqgmt_t1-8VhD-XUQYJ4qORjXz-mbMDv1W7JqgwrSN8

Algorithm is stated on page 3 under **batch balancing** heading.

Answer (score 0):

You can use class weights like in:

```
    model.fit(X_train, y_train, class_weight=class_weights)
```

Where class_weights is a dictionary. For example, class_weights = {0: 4, 1: 10, 2:1}, which means that for every 4 samples in class 0, we have 10 samples in class 1 and 1 sample in class 2.

In your particular example, you might just set the appropriate parameters for only the positive and negative class of interest.

Comment: there is no positive or negative class, there are only positive and negative instances of a class. and i don't think class_weights would work it just gives classes a relative weight, what i want is to precisely weight either negative or positive instances of a class. it's much more like the following
{class 0 negative instance: weight 2/3,
class 1 positive instances: weight 3/4}
just giving you a big picture of what i am trying to achieve

Comment: Can't you split each class into a positive subclass and a negative subclass, and then do class weights for each?  I think it might work with some adjustment to the loss function (like splitting the two cases).

Comment: there should be another way this seems very naive. Should i maybe implement my own cost function?

Comment: I would think so. If the goal is to replicate the paper, I think that you probably would have to write your own batch_generator too, to extract the batch information.